# Element aligned to another centered element that's after it

Tags: html, css

I wonder how to achieve styling like in the following mockup?

[image: mockup]

The red box is centered relatively to parent element. Blue box takes all the space between lefte edge of its parent and right edge of blue box. And white space is just part of parent's background. Red box is 300px wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this using CSS tables:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/z61bpskg/)

Just set the parent element's `display` to `table`, and add `table-layout: fixed`. Set the `display` of the children elements to `table-cell`, and give them widths of `100%`. In doing so, they will fluidly fill the remaining area.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child fixed"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

```
.parent {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.parent > .child {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.parent > .child.fixed {
    width: 300px;
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to avoid CSS tables, you could also use [**`calc()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to set the widths of the elements.

In this case `width: calc((100% - 300px) / 2)` would work.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2wLt334q/)

```
.parent > .child {
    height: 100px;
    width: calc((100% - 300px) / 2);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.parent > .child.fixed {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Just take [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) for [**`calc()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) into consideration.

Comment: @John ..why not? It's there for a reason.

Comment: It's a hack, it shows the lack of understanding of how CSS works. The authors even hacked several things (`vertical-alignment` and `height: 100%;` don't work correctly most of the time) but what does work all the way back to IE4/Opera 4 is `float` which is what people are supposed to use, not `display` and `table` hacks.

Comment: To put it another way: if you're going to spend the time to help people teach them to do it the *right* way, not *any* way. There are heaps of reasons I've built my own platform but it can be summed up in one: people don't write code correctly especially when it's wildly easy to do the right thing.

Comment: This is perfectly acceptable, @John. Your criticism is over personal preference. Get off your high-horse.

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to replace empty child to something like .parent > .child.fixed:after? I tried to style it with display: table-cell and content: "" and it didn't work. EDIT: Fixed. I just had to style parent:after and it works perefectly.

Comment: @MatixYo It likely doesn't work because pseudo elements are added as children elements. Therefore the generated content would be inside the element `.child.fixed`, rather than being a sibling element. The pseudo element should be after the `.parent` element.